# Get "timeout" command from GNU coreutils 8 on RHEL 5.7 machine

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, package-management

What is the best way to install the Gnu `timeout` command on an RHEL 5.7 machine?

I would prefer to install with `yum`, but I can compile from source if that is the only way.

`timeout` was introduced in Coreutils 8+, but RHEL 5.7 only has Coreutils 5.97, so far as I can tell.

Do I have to install from source? Will that interfere with yum?

Comment: I'd advise against it.  On my Gentoo Box coreutils is dependent upon binutils, which depends on gcc, ie if you replace coreutils you break the symbols in binutils, and then your toolchain, and nothing will work...  the ./configure should check but if the configure passes, you have been warned...!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

coreutils doesn't depend on gcc in Red Hat land. That's just daft :)
Probably the handiest is to use the script that I based the timeout command on:

http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/timeout